# How to put Elements in ListView in android?

Tags: android, element

I am using this code to retreive Elements from a html page.

```
// Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
Elements games = doc.select("tr > td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");

// Iterator over those elements
ListIterator<Element> gameIt = games.listIterator();

while (gameIt.hasNext()) {
// Get the title of the game
Element title = gameIt.next();

System.out.println(title.text());

// Unneeded elements
Element platform = gameIt.next();
Element genre = gameIt.next();

// Get the release date of the game
Element release = gameIt.next();
System.out.println(release.text() + "\n@@@@@@");
}
```

How would i go about putting these elements in a ListView with two textviews for the title element and the other for the release element?

EDIT-gives me this error

```
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050001
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at    android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2049)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:375)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:366)
 08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1970)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1139)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
08-15 14:49:37.730: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18945):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
```

Here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/outputTextView"
/>
<ListView    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/list"   android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It didnt work correctly and the answer was confusing

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load these elements to populate a list in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065756/how-to-load-these-elements-to-populate-a-list-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListView is abstracted away from the items themselves and therefore refers to a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) for the actual items.

So you have to put the actual items in a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and then call ListView.[setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)(ListAdapter yourListAdapter).

Comment: I would suggest you go through this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) for ListView. This website has a good set of tutorials that I've found handy.

Comment: Also, the Android SDK comes with examples of how to implement many different sorts of Lists including what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks alot! That tutorial helped me! It was a small error i was doing

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with the following conditions:

1. You are using a ListActivity
2. You create a POJO for a Game.

**Code:**

```
List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
while (gameIt.hasNext()) {

  // Get the title of the game
  Element title = gameIt.next();

  // Unneeded elements
  Element platform = gameIt.next();
  Element genre = gameIt.next();

  // Get the release date of the game
  Element release = gameIt.next();

  Game game = new Game(title, platform, genre, release);
  games.add(game);
}

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Game>(this, R.id.YOUR_LIST_ITEM_VIEW, games);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Look at my edit above. Get an error. I believe something is wrong with my layout

Comment: [Please RTFM](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)